# Laravel 5 request - How to show individual validation errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a request in L5 to handle saving a contact which looks like so:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class AddContactRequest extends Request {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'category_ids' => 'required|array|exists:categories,id',
            'gender' => 'required|in:Male,Female',
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'company' => 'required',
            'position' => 'required',
            'website_url' => 'url',
            'facebook_url' => 'url',
            'twitter_url' => 'url',
            'instagram_url' => 'url',
            'misc_url1' => 'url',
            'misc_url2' => 'url',
            'address_1' => 'required',
            'citytown' => 'required',
            'postcode' => 'required',
            'country_id' => 'required|integer|exists:countries,id',
            'work_email' => 'email',
            'home_email' => 'email',
            'work_phone' => '',
            'mobile_phone' => '',
            'home_phone' => ''
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Error messages for validation rules
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'category_ids.required' => 'You must select at least one category.',
            'category_ids.array' => 'Categories must be an array.',
            'category_ids.exists' => 'The category does not exist.',
            'gender.required' => 'The gender field is required.',
            'gender.in' => 'The gender is invalid.',
            'first_name.required' => 'The first name field is required.',
            'last_name.required' => 'The last name field is required.',
            'company.required' => 'The company field is required.',
            'position.required' => 'The position field is required.',
            'website_url.url' => 'The website URL is not a valid URL.',
            'facebook_url.url' => 'The facebook URL is not a valid URL.',
            'twitter_url.url' => 'The twitter URL is not a valid URL.',
            'instagram_url.url' => 'The instagram URL is not a valid URL.',
            'misc_url1.url' => 'The miscellaneous URL 1 field is not a valid URL',
            'misc_url2.url' => 'The miscellaneous URL 2 field is not a valid URL',
            'address_1.required' => 'The address 1 field is required.',
            'citytown.required' => 'The city / town field is required.',
            'postcode.required' => 'The postcode field is required.',
            'country_id.required' => 'The country field is required.',
            'country_id.integer' => 'The country field must contain an integer.',
            'country_id.exists' => 'The country is invalid.',
            'work_email.email' => 'The work email field is not a valid email address.',
            'home_email.email' => 'The home email field is not a valid email address.'
        ];
    }

}
```

When the validation fails I'm able to output all of the errors in my view with the following code:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

But I want to show individual errors and add a class to the form group if that field has an error like so:

```
<div class="form-group <?php echo ($messages->has('first_name')) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <label for="first_name" class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-4">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        {!! Form::text('first_name', '', array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

The $messages->has() method doesn't seem to work though I get the following error:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

2/2
ErrorException in 6351f2a902813f4fd7aa70b7ef38354d line 34:
Undefined variable: messages (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\fourteen-ten\resources\views\admin\contacts\add.blade.php)
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK thanks to Sulthan I was able to figure it out. Instead of:

```
$messages->has('field_name')
```

I should use:

```
$errors->has('field_name')
```

Answer (score 14):

To display error individually. You shall place this under each element

```
<div class="error">{{ $errors->first('category_ids') }}</div>
```

Note :

You shall create a class named as `error` in your css for this.

This will display the errors only if any occcurs

Comment: This works well, but better to use condition (if-else) for displaying the error container.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is the simple procedure:

```
$rules=array('mobile'=>'required|numeric');
$validator=Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);

if($validator->fails()){
    $failedRules=$validator->failed();
    if(isset($failedRules['signInType']['Required'])){
        return response()->json(["status"=>"Error","message"=>"Please enter signInType"]);
    }

    if(isset($failedRules['signInType']['Numeric'])){
        return response()->json(["status"=>"Error","message"=>"mobile must be numeric"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry! i have posted the code in that way because i don't know how to post the comment

Comment: You need [50 reputation to comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Therefor, you can ask questions and answerr questions and earn reputation if someone upvotes one of your contribution.